# Implementing asyncIO with pysimplegui

Tags: python, python-asyncio, pysimplegui

I am trying to implement asyncio with pysimplegui in python.
In this GUI example, two buttons (button2 and button3) emulate a long task to accomplish.

**Goal**:

- Be able to go back to the GUI interface even if a called function (through button) takes time to return the result.

**Expected result:**

- If button2 or button3 or both are pushed, they both continue to execute their tasks and users can go back to the GUI to carry on with other tasks.

**Current result:**

- As soon as either button2 or button3 is pushed, the tasks is blocked and contionue until the end and the GUI hangs until the end.

[image: current issue]

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import asyncio
import time

sg.theme('Light Blue 3')
# This design pattern simulates button callbacks
# This implementation uses a simple "Dispatch Dictionary" to store events and functions

# The callback functions
async def button1():
    print('Button 1 callback')
    return 'nothing'

async def button2():
    print('Button 2 callback')
    for i in range(1,20):
        await asyncio.sleep(3)
        print(f"Button 2: {i}")
    return f"button2 end"

async def button3():
    print('Button 3 callback')
    for i in range(1,10):
        await asyncio.sleep(3)
        print(f"Button 3: {i}")
    return f"button3: end"


# Lookup dictionary that maps button to function to call
dispatch_dictionary = {'1':button1, '2':button2, '3':button3}
# Layout the design of the GUI
layout = [[sg.Text('Please click a button', auto_size_text=True)],
        [sg.Button('1'), sg.Button('2'), sg.Button('3'), sg.Quit()]]
# Show the Window to the user__TIMEOUT__
window = sg.Window('Button callback example', layout)
# Event loop. Read buttons, make callbacks
while True:
    # Read the Window
    event, values = window.read()
    if event in ('Quit', sg.WIN_CLOSED):
        break
    if event == '__TIMEOUT__':
        continue
    # Lookup event in function dictionary
    if event in dispatch_dictionary:
        func_to_call = dispatch_dictionary[event]   # get function from dispatch dictionary
        print(asyncio.run(func_to_call()))
    else:
        print('Event {} not in dispatch dictionary'.format(event))

window.close()
# All done!
sg.popup_ok('Done')
```

I thought that I applied async/wait according to the rules. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 4):

`asyncio.run()` executes one coroutine and blocks until it is done. It does *NOT* start a parallel thread to run the coroutine in.

You have two options:

1. Don't use asyncio, use Threading to start a new thread for each long operation.
2. Start a thread with an asyncio eventloop in it at the start of the program, then use `asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe()` to schedule a coroutine onto the event loop from the main GUI thread.

I will explain option 2 here.. Example at the start of your program:

```
from threading import Thread

def asyncloop(loop):
    # Set loop as the active event loop for this thread
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    # We will get our tasks from the main thread so just run an empty loop    
    loop.run_forever()

# create a new loop
loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
# Create the new thread, giving loop as argument
t = Thread(target=asyncloop, args=(loop,))
# Start the thread
t.start()
```

Later in the button event code (in main thread):

```
asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(func_to_call(), loop)
```

This will schedule the coroutine to run as a parallel task inside the thread we created.

Comment: Note: I am not familiar with pysimplegui but typically all your GUI operations need to happen from the same thread. So if you start new threads or schedule coroutines onto the worker thread described here, you cannot perform GUI operations from them.

Comment: Thanks @vaizki for your prompt reply.  
I have been discouraged to use threading in favour of asyncio, because the poor scalability of threading.
Besides:
> "One of the cool advantages of asyncio is that it scales far better than threading . Each task takes far fewer resources and less time to create than a thread, so creating and running more of them works well. This example just creates a separate task for each site to download, which works out quite well."

Comment: I suspected this and use asyncio a *LOT* myself as well. This is why I went through the example of creating ONE extra thread for an asyncio loop. You cannot run the GUI eventloop and the asyncio eventloop in the same thread unless your GUI library has an asyncio API.

Comment: can you expand on your explanations, I am not sure how to integrate the asyncio eventloop with the event loop (while True) usually used in Pysimplegui.

Comment: @AJN Basically after the `t.start()` you can put the main `while` loop, as that will be the GUI Thread now. Basically all you do is wait for clicks and just call `asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(func_to_call(), loop)`. No other action would happen here. The other thread that it gonna execute the actions, e.g. what has to be done on button press is queued in that coroutine, as started by `t = Thread(target=asyncloop, args=(loop,))`, so in other words in, `asyncloop(…)`, the `loop.run_forever()` will be your workhorse.

Comment: How do we shut down the program when the user hits quit? `window.close()` is not enough because the thread has to be shut down, however I tried `loop.stop()
t.join()` at the end of the script but that didn't help - the app freezes. A full working example would be great.